# Script editor, automatic end time

Tags: time, editor, google-forms

Full disclosure, I am in no way a programmer of any kind.  My library was looking for an easier way for multiple locations to add events to the public calendar.

Eventually I stumbled upon [this script](http://www.shekhargovindarajan.com/google/google-apps-script-automatically-create-calendar-events-from-google-form/) which I was able to adapt for our needs.  However, the one change they would like is to have the end time default to 2 hours later.  For example, if an event starts at 1 then the end time automatically defaults to 3.

Can anyone show me what change in the script I need to make for that to happen?  [Here is the test form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfhTI6Day3hzG51yk-pMAtHQEJGlhZ6_MwiXz-dSfWmWS-61w/viewform) that we use to enter the dates.  Right now the end time is entered manually but I'd imagine that would have to be removed, correct?

Any help in figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
//insert your google calendar ID
var calendarId = "ID-FOR-TEST-CALENDAR";

//index (starting from 1) of each column in the sheet
var titleIndex = 2;
var descriptionIndex = 3;
var startDateIndex = 4;
var endDateIndex = 5;
var googleCalendarIndex = 6;

/*
find the row where the Google Calendar Event ID is blank or null
The data of this row will be used to create a new calendar event
*/
function findRow(sheet) {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
 var values = dataRange.getValues();

 for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
 if(values[i][googleCalendarIndex-1]=="" || values[i][googleCalendarIndex-1]==null)
 newEvent(i+1);
 } 
 };


/* 
get the data of the new row by calling getSheetData() and 
create a new Calendar event by calling submitToGoogleCalendar()
*/

function newEvent(row){ 
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var eventId = submitToGoogleCalendar(getSheetData(sheet,row),null)
 if(eventId!=null) 
 sheet.getRange(row,googleCalendarIndex,1,1).setValue(eventId);
};


/* 
Store the data of a row in an Array
*/

function getSheetData(sheet,row)
{
 var data = new Array();

 data.title=sheet.getRange(row,titleIndex,1,1).getValue();
 data.description=sheet.getRange(row,descriptionIndex,1,1).getValue();

 data.startDate = sheet.getRange(row,startDateIndex,1,1).getValue();
 data.endDate = sheet.getRange(row,endDateIndex,1,1).getValue();

 return data; 
};

/* 
if a cell is edited in the sheet, get all the data of the corresponding row and 
create a new calendar event (after deleting the old event) by calling submitToGoogleCalendar() 
*/

function dataChanged(event){

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var row = event.range.getRow();

 var eventId = sheet.getRange(row,googleCalendarIndex,1,1).getValue();

 var eventId = submitToGoogleCalendar(getSheetData(sheet,row),eventId)

 if(eventId!=null)
 sheet.getRange(row,googleCalendarIndex,1,1).setValue(eventId);

};


/* 
This function creates an event in the Google Calendar and returns the calendar event ID 
which is stored in the last column of the sheet 
*/
function submitToGoogleCalendar(sheetData,eventId) {
 // some simple validations ;-)
 if(sheetData.title == "" || sheetData.startDate == "" || sheetData.startDate == null)
 return null;

 var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
 var start = new Date(sheetData.startDate);
 var end = new Date(sheetData.endDate);

 // some simple date validations
 if(start > end)
 return null;

 var event = null;

 //if eventId is null (when called by newEvent()) create a new calendar event
 if(eventId==null)
 {
 event = cal.createEvent(sheetData.title, start, end, {
 description : sheetData.description, 
 });
 return event.getId(); 
 }
 /*
 else if the eventid is not null (when called by dataChanged()), delete the calendar event 
 and create a new event with the modified data by calling this function again
 */
 else
 {
 event = cal.getEventSeriesById(eventId);
 event.deleteEventSeries(); 
 return submitToGoogleCalendar(sheetData,null);
 }

 return event.getId();

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having tried it myself, I believe you could do it like this:

```
function submitToGoogleCalendar(sheetData,eventId) {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var start = new Date(sheetData.startDate);
  var end = new Date(sheetData.endDate);
  end.setHours(start.getHours() + 2);
```

...where the last line is the new line added to your original script.

To your question wether the end time should be removed, I would say yes, it should be removed.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It partially works.  When I remove the time option from End Date, the script no longer adds the Event ID to the spreadsheet.  However, if I leave the time in there AND the additional line of code you provided, I can enter whatever time in the form and the end time will default to 2 hours later.  Granted, it defeats the purpose if users have to manually type an end time anyway.

Comment: You don't really need the `sheetData.endDate` reference anymore. If you remove the end date from the Google form, you can also remove the reference in the script and just rely on the start date. Just change the line where you define your variable like this: `var end = new Date(sheetData.startDate);`

Comment: That did the trick!  Thank you for taking the time to help with this problem.  Much appreciated!